# inverse result of query_to_xml() PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I am using a `servlet(servlet1)` via a `GET` method from `httpurlconnection()` function  in order to get the XML generated by an another `servlet(servlet2)` connected to a `postgreSQL` Database.

The XML generated by the `servlet2` via the statement:

```
 select query_to_xml('select * from test', true, false, '');
```

I initialize an `httpurlconnection()` from `servlet1` to `servlet2` and I stored in a string "`response1`" the output like that:

```
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response1.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
 //The output in console
 System.out.println(response1.toString());
```

The XML is stored in the string "`response1`" as:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/pro/inc/form.css;jsessionid=D965FA3338EC4E88F6F7AA0B64308446" /> 
</head>  
<body>       
    <p><alltests_00_with_defects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <row>
            <n5>a</n5> 
            <n4>b</n4> 
            <n3>c</n3> 
            <n2>d</n2> 
            <n1>e</n1> 

        <row>
        <row>
            <n5>a</n5> 
            <n4>b</n4> 
            <n3>c</n3> 
            <n2>d</n2> 
            <n1>e</n1> 

        <row>       
</html>
```

Until here, it's cool!!

Now, I am looking for a solution that can convert BACK the XML generated to data values.

Any ideas?